# Attaching an existing Evernote resource to a new Evernote note

Tags: evernote

According to the [Evernote docs](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/creating_notes.php), a resource is created along with a note that contains and references it.

Say I have a note with a resource, and I want to create a new note with exactly the same resource.

Is there a way to create the new note and use the existing resource, instead of creating a new duplicate resource?

Reasons for that:

1. I get the existing note with resources using `getNote` API call, and I have no reason to pass `with_resource_data=True`, which will consume bandwidth.
2. I don't want to consume extra quota by uploading the resource data *again* with the new note.

I'm using the Python Evernote SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There's no way to do that. 
A resource is linked to a specific note and can't be shared amongst notes.
That's why there's a noteGuid attribute in the Resource object.

So you'll have to get the resource with the note, attach it to the new note and upload the new note.

It's not optimal but it's the only way...